# How to filter multiple characters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way how to filter multiple characters during analyzing in ElastisSearch? We would like to setup it so if user searches '**botled**' then he get the documents that include '**bottled**' or '**botttled**', etc., i.e no matter double, tripple letters.

I have looking for solution in token filters https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html, but it seems that none of them matches our requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default elasticsearch text field is tokenized based on whitespace, i.e. only words are indexed and are searchable.

would regex search work for you?

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "user": {
                "value": "b+o+t+t+l+e+d+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

b+ --> one or more occurrence of b

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is also applicable. Although I originally thought that the repeating chars would be removed just during the analysis, but your solution is also helpful.

By the way, I found out that we really needed something more like a "fuzzy search" rather than what I was asking for, but that's my stupidity.

Thank you for your time.